# Dojo onBeforeTransitionIn not firing

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.mobile

I have a problem with transition events in Dojo mobile views (TweetViews). I want to perform an action on view change (like loading content dynamically). So far I have tried the following:

```
on(document.getElementById("add"),"onBeforeTransitionIn", function(){
    console.log("test");
});
```

`onAfterTransitionIn`, `onBeforeTransitionOut` and `onAfterTransitionOut` also do not work.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo seperates widgets (like `dojox/mobile` views) from DOM nodes (like the one you get with `document.getElementById()`). This means that you cannot use the `onBeforeTransitionIn` event handler on a plain DOM node, like you're actually trying to do.

Luckily for you widgets adapt their ID from the DOM node, so it should still be `"add"`. To retrieve a widget by its ID, you use:

```js
var myView = registry.byId("add");
```

The `dojo/on` module should only be used with DOM events. You might actually make it work with custom widget events, but I don't think it's the correct way of handling these events. Normally you should use the widget `on()` function, for example:

```js
myView.on("beforeTransitionIn", function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Also note that you leave out the `"on"` part in front of the event name. You also do that with the `dojo/on` module, so it might be interesting to remember this for future use.

I also made a small JSFiddle to demonstrate the event handling, which you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/qct3L/.

Answer (score 0):

Since a mobile view is a widget, you should try to register your event on the widget instead of the DOM node. Example:

```
on(registry.byId("add"), "onBeforeTransitionIn", ...)
```

registry refers to http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html

Comment: Tried that already, still no effect :/. Events like "click" work tho, so it might be something related to transition.